# Tick labels in d3.js scatter plot chart getting cut off in Firefox 13.0.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, d3.js

I am currently making a scatter plot chart using d3.js, which is really similar to what is in this link:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/dot-chart.html

My problem is that when I make the y-axis' tick labels really long and accordingly increase the padding size of the SVG elements with CSS, part of the tick labels get cut off in Firefox 13.0.1 yet not in Safari 6.0.

In the CSS, I increased the SVG elements' padding size by adding this to the code in the link:

```
svg{
    padding: 200px;
}
```

To increase the length of the y-axis' tick labels, I added this in the d3 script (right after the yAxis variable is instantiated):

```
yAxis.tickFormat(function(d){return "lolzReallyLongTickLabels"});
```

Increasing the padding size of the svg elements prevents the cutting off of the tick labels in Safari 6.0 but not Firefox 13.0.1. How do I make the long tick labels not get cutoff in Firefox?

Comment: Give us the generated SVG/HTML/CSS (say in jsfiddle) and we might be able to help a little better. Sounds less like a D3 problem and more like SVG / CSS.

Answer (score 0):

By now you likely have your answer. But if  not, I found a page which seems to deal with your question by creating an axis and then rotating it.

http://bl.ocks.org/hlvoorhees/5986172